# SQL: Return single value with multiple criteria

Tags: sql

Maybe a simple question but I don't get the right results so I hope you can help. In this case I have two different tables, one table filled with Order data (OrderID, Supplier and Order Value). The other table is filled with Invoice data (Invoice ID, Supplier, invoice value, Invoice value -10%, Invoice value +10%).

What I need is an overview based on the order table whereby there is a match between Order supplier and invoice supplier + the order value which is in the range of -10% and +10% of the invoice value. It doesn't matter which order belongs to which invoice, I only need to know whether there is a match 'yes' or 'no'.

Example: In the order table you can see row 1 (order 100). It belongs to supplier A and has a value of 10. In the invoice table you can see that row 4 meets the requirements (Supplier = A and order value: 10 -> range between 9 and 11). This should result in a 'Yes'.

Hope you can help!

Thanks in advance,

Greets!

Order table:

[image]

Invoice table:

[image]

Comment: Is this SQL server? MySQL? PostgreSQL? MSSQL? Or a different RDBMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to now if there is a match, use `case` with `exists`.  However, I'm going to propose returning a matching invoice id.  The value will be `NULL` if there are no matches:

```
select o.*,
       (select i.id
        from invoice i
        where i.supplier = o.supplier and
              o.value between i.value * 0.9 and i.value * 1.1
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as a_matching_invoice_id
from orders o
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
select * 
from Order as o
join Invoice as i
on (o.Supplier = i.Supplier and o.Value between i.ValueMinus10Percent and i.ValuePlus10Percent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a subselect:

`select *, (select 1 from Supplier s where o.value - 10 > s.value and o.value + 10 < s.value and so on) as YesOrNo from table Order o;`

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.* into temp from order a,invoice b
where a.supplier=b.supplier and a.value=b.value

select *,case when value between min and max then state='yes'
else state='no'
end
from temp
```